# How to add a 3rd party local maven repository to android project

Tags: java, android, maven, android-studio, jar

I have been provided an SDK to work on, which contains a maven-local-metadata file, an .aar file, .pom file and .jar file. How do I add this to my project. I tried pasting it to the local .m2 file but it didn't work (is there any specific way)and also adding as a new .aar/.jar module in the file option didn't work.
any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: My library structure for reference]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the files in the local .m2 repository in the correct structure and youre good. no need to add in the libs folder.

Note - If working with .aar files just as a modules

Comment: you went from "I tried pasting it to the local .m2 file but it didn't work" to "Just add the files in the local .m2 repository in the correct structure and youre good"... a depiction of the changes you made to your local .m2 would have been great.

Comment: @EugenioLopez, sorry for the bad answer. What I was doing wrong was that my folder structure in the .m2 folder was different from the project folder structure

Comment: oh got it, thanks for the response. For some reason the .m2 route didnt work for me even though I have a similar folder structure minus the jar.  I got it working by plucking out and importing the .aar file.

Answer (score 0):

Create libs folder in your root directory then add your files there Check out the screenshot [image]

and then on BuildGradle (Project)

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: do I add all the files in the libs folder (.aar, .pom, .jar), I had added .jar but it didnt work

Comment: I did this but it gives this error: Cannot open a library at 'FileMapping(from=C:\AndroidProjects\project-sdk-2\SDK-Sample-app-master\app\libs\sdk-0.0.1-sources.jar, to=C:\Users\{username}\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2

Comment: delete .idea folder from your project folder then sync again and run it will work

Comment: It didnt work, I have edited my question to include an image of the project structure can you have a look at it and see its implmentation.

Comment: just delete the build folder with libs folder and then try to sync again

Answer (score 0):

When pointing to dependencies that are residing within your system, you can create a lib folder and copy/move the jar files, but make sure to specify the location of the jar files in the pom.xml

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.some.group</groupId>
   <artifactId>jar-name</artifactId>
   <version>1.0</version>
   <scope>system</scope>
   <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/yourJar.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Comment: So I move the jar files and not the .pom and .aar file and use the new path in the .pom file. right?

Comment: Correct! place the jar file in a directory (lib) within your project and then refer that jar as specified in my previous answer.